# Explicit Encode and Decode with AntiXssLibrary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, antixsslibrary

I know we can make ASP.NET MVC project to use AntiXssEncoder as a default encoder but sometimes we need to explicitly encode/decode html/url/js inside the code.

Despite the fact that nearly all methods inside AntiXSS class have been marked as deprecated, so what are we supposed to do in these situations? Is there any alternative or we should go ahead and use them?

Answer (score 0):

It seems pretty much all encoder methods have a new implementation in **Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder** class.